# Android widget update called twice after device boot

Tags: android, widget, boot, reboot

After device reboot I receive first APPWIDGET_ENABLED and then **twice** APPWIDGET_UPDATE.
I spent quite some hours googling this without result.
Is anybody experiencing the same? Have you found a way to avoid calling the update twice?

Here's some code:

```
    <receiver android:name=".Widget" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
             <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" /> 
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider" android:resource="@xml/button_widget_provider" />
    </receiver>



public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
    super.onReceive(context, intent);
    final String action = intent.getAction();

    if  (AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE.equals(action) ) {
        Log.i(TAG, "update");
    } else if (AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_ENABLED.equals(action) ) {
        Log.i(TAG, "enabled");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Have you found a way to avoid calling the update twice?

You have no control over how many times you are updated. That is up to the home screen and the app widget framework.

Comment: Do you mean that I can get updated n times (not just 2) even though I only have 1 instance of the widget on the desktop?

Comment: @sara: Yes. There is no guarantee over how many times the home screen will request an update.

Comment: Glad to hear that my widget relies on a nondeterministic platform! Is there a way to work around this?

Comment: @sara: Since I do not know what your problem is, I cannot answer this. App widgets should not care how many times they get updated.

Comment: I think they do care because during every update they perform tasks that consume time and resources. Performing the same tasks multiple times is simply a waste.

Comment: @sara: Ah, now we are getting somewhere. Simply record a timestamp of when you did the expensive work, and skip the expensive work if the current update is too soon after the last round of expensive work.

Comment: Makes sense but I'm afraid this will frustrate many users. I want my widget to do the expensive work when the user asks for it but not because the homescreen just decides to fire an update event multiple times. Is there a way to distinguish between the 2 update events?

Comment: @sara: "When the user asks for it" does not need to go through the same update path as updates requested by the home screen. Assuming that "when the user asks for it" is referring to some sort of button on the app widget itself, you are welcome to set up that `PendingIntent` to do whatever you want. And, you are welcome to update the app widget from anywhere you want -- you are not limited to doing so from `onUpdate()` of your `AppWidgetProvider`.

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
import android.content.Context;

public class CopyOfWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {

    private static ArrayList<Integer> widgets = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] widgetIDs) {
        super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, widgetIDs);

        for (int widgetID : widgetIDs) {
            if (!widgets.contains(widgetID)) {
                widgets.add(widgetID);
                // this code will run only ONCE after reboot
                // loop is necessary in cases where there were more than one
                // instances of widget before reboot
            }
        }
    }

}
```