# Can os and Home screen update the android app widget at will?

Tags: java, android, widget

I want to make and app with widget to present some data,and i want to be sure it will not become a battery drain source and add all the checks i have to,so there is no problem.

So android documentation actually says that ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE may be sent in response to a new instance for this AppWidget provider having been instantiated, the requested update interval having lapsed, or the system booting.

But i came into this bizarre answer here

[Android widget update called twice after device boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13363840/android-widget-update-called-twice-after-device-boot)

that suggest that the home screen can actually update your widget n times at will.Seems bizarre,and i cant find something similar,do i really have no control over this?

Answer (score 0):

As in the previous answer you found, there is no way to limit how many times the home screen might update the widget - it is responsibility of the homescreen and you cannot control this.

You could add a limit in your update implementation instead. For example, record the time the checks are made. If the widget update is requested again too soon after the last one, ignore it until the required amount of time passes.